# How to get the closest select option based on a number

Tags: jquery

I have a select option based on a minimum unit, by default it's 1 to 100. 
If the minimum unit is 5 then it's 5 - 10 - 15 - 20 .. 500.

Now it can also happen that there will be a number other then the minimum unit lets say 6, which then has to be pre selected. If it's lower then I just take the first option.

But what if it's higher so now it's 6 how can I then have the next option (10) selected?

```
    <select id='quantity'></select>

        var minunit = 5;
var list = [];

if (minunit > 1) {
  for (var i = minunit; i <= (100 * minunit);
    (i += minunit)) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  $('#quantity').empty();

  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $('<option>').val(list[i]).text(list[i]).appendTo('#quantity');
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx1r5f32/2/)

Comment: Instead of disliking, tell me what is wrong? This isn't helping anybody

Comment: How is it not clear if there is an option 5,10, 15 (etc), and I have 6 I need the (next) closest option (10) selected.

Comment: E.g when unit is 8 your list is 8, 16, 24.. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really understand your question at first.
I think you wanted to preselect a value based on a number right?

Than this would be the solution:

```
var selectNumber = 8
selectNumber = Math.ceil(selectNumber / minunit) * minunit;

$("#quantity option[value="+selectNumber+"]").attr("selected","selected");
```

I hope this helps.